# How to reference array values from array defined in interface?

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I have the following interface defined:

```js
interface Cities {
    names: ["New York", "Chicago", "Los Angeles"]
    // rest of the parameters
}
```

Now I have a function which takes in a parameter city which should only be the ones defined in names:

```js
const getPopulation = (name: Cities["names"]) => {
    // return population of city 'name'
}
```

However, the above would/does not work since `Cities["names"]` is an array. I want to reference the array values (i.e. "New York" etc.). How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an enum instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cities["names"]` gives a tuple type which you can further convert to a `union` type using `Cities['names'][number]` as function parameter:

```
const getPopulation = (name: Cities["names"][number]) => {
    // return population of city 'name'
}
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtaiKDIKMjJHooADC8go+lAAG9FCUSpwGMgCqAANoAIgAcpAJKBwmR4oL+IL6WpYAxmPAZaBBS94MIKpxmDB9IKALqKAC+wQQnEENF1qFo8AIUXxFHgXgAvKAABTc5D5UCM1DMwRCr36g38zjsRDSH4GgCUoBdAD42RzOSonASyF4CHaHf7nUlUrB5HhQAByYOlk3BFQ4BoeTOgRDwAYMEHsGjfNxmZjsJWQfiwaDqRKt+B6EReQUAUVWPJq+qSOMF4AcqFLwlFEkFQRUAHlvmRdoJ+1pIMdUI4FK5pCWnE2dKMsPoUAhEDDhFdOxJm9ERAYODi3QsGwXDcEEJRAA)

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
enum City {
  NewYork="New York";
  Chicago="Chicago";
  LosAngeles="Los Angeles";
}
const getPopulation = (name: City): number => {
    // return population of city 'name'
}
```

Or you can do this

```
type City = "New York" | "Chicago" | "Los Angeles"
const getPopulation = (name: City): number => {
    // return population of city 'name'
}
```

Please let me know if this is useful. I didn't fully understand the question. But I think you are trying to enforce that name is not just an string, It has to be a string inside and group of options. If you can provide further details It would be great to help you better!

Comment: I was looking more for getting the array values union since the `Cities` interface has more parameters. But this was still helpful to know `enum`. Thanks!